# TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function

Tags: jquery, slider, hosting, typeerror

Is there someway jquery slider dependent on server? I am using jquery library and Ui for jquery range slider. There is only one  jquery library so i think no question on any conflict. The slider works perfectly fine in my linux server which gives correct output. But when i pushed the code is my IIS server i am getting this error which says TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function in mozilla browser and Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  in chrome browser. I am just wandering if server is anyway be the cause for it. :( Please suggest if anyone face something similar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({
          range: "min",
          animate: true,
          value:0,
          min: 0,
          max: 30,
          step: 1,
          slide: function(event, ui) {
            update(2,ui.value); //changed
          }
      });}
```

Comment: Use a network tool like Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 debugging tools to see what is actually loading from the server. It may just be failing to return one of your JS files.

Comment: perhaps some other script (above the slider) causes errors, which blocks the execution of scripts below it. Make a demo page with only the basic data (js + css + html) for slier to work and test it. In fireox, in console, where you get the TypeError.. in what file is it?

Comment: @andrew thanks for quick reply.. but i dont think there's some errors in script above it since its running perfectly correct for the linux server (the website is uploaded in both linux and IIS server). It's in the html file from where i am call slider() function.

Comment: @RahulUkil perhaps there is some combability issue with some other js script in IIS enviroment - thats all i am saying. Thats why i told you to make minimal page for slider, to check just that.

Comment: Sounds like you've not included jQuery or jQueryUI

Comment: if you've included only the core jQuery UI, you also have to add the slider module.

Answer (score 38):

Use both Jquery and ui, then it will work.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Work for me. I test any things

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error message. In the end it turned out that my code loaded jQuery twice, including a version of jQuery that was just too old. Once I made sure that only one, recent version of jQuery was linked into my code, the error went away.

Maybe one of your servers (the IIS server) is serving up an out of date version of jQuery?

So check what version of jQuery you are using. This one works fine for me:

```js
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had the same problem and tried including the non-slim versions of both jQuery and jQuery UI but this did not fix it. Turned out two versions of jQuery were loading!

Answer (score 1):

For me running rails you can individually specify which jQuery UI elements are listed and I didn't have slider in the pipeline. Adding that in fixed the problem!

Comment: How have you added actually? I am struggling

Answer (score 1):

Make 100% sure you are not including jquery.js lib twice or more.

Check inside other js packed files that you include in your page.