# how to make change in jquery ui slider with the change in input value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have made price range jquery ui slider. i want to make change in slider when user put correct details in input field. i have tried some code but it was not working on my particular project but  was working fine alone. so can someone please tell me what "exactly" i have to write?

```js
$('#price_range').slider({
  range: true,
  min: 100,
  max: 50000,
  values: [100, 50000],
  step: 1,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
    $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
    filter_data();
  }
});


$("#price_range .tic").each(function(ind, elem) {
  var c = $(elem).attr("class").split(" ");
  var i = c.indexOf("tic");
  c.splice(i, 1);
  var pos = c.join("");
  $(".slide-labels ." + pos).position({
    my: "center bottom",
    at: "right-5 top-4 ",
    of: $(elem)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group three-list">
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <input id="hidden_minimum_price" value="100" />
  <input id="hidden_maximum_price" value="50000" />
  <p id="price_show">100 - 50000</p>
  <div class="slide-labels">
    <div class="label pos-0 first">
      $0
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-1">
      $10,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-2">
      $20,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-3">
      $30,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-4">
      $40,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-5 last">
      $50,000
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="price_range">
    <div class="tic pos-1">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-2">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-3">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in above code when i put some value in input field it was giving error: $(...).slider is not a function.

please be specific about what i have to do. if possible then show running code. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040459/typeerror-slider-is-not-a-function) - put jQueryUi import *after* the jQuery one

Comment: not exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in your imports, as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040459/typeerror-slider-is-not-a-function) suggested.

You should just add the jQuery UI import and its stylesheet, and the slider will work correctly.

```js
$('#price_range').slider({
  range: true,
  min: 100,
  max: 50000,
  values: [100, 50000],
  step: 1,
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
    $('#hidden_minimum_price').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#hidden_maximum_price').val(ui.values[1]);
    //filter_data();
  }
});


$("#price_range .tic").each(function(ind, elem) {
  var c = $(elem).attr("class").split(" ");
  var i = c.indexOf("tic");
  c.splice(i, 1);
  var pos = c.join("");
  $(".slide-labels ." + pos).position({
    my: "center bottom",
    at: "right-5 top-4 ",
    of: $(elem)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="list-group three-list">
  <h3>Price</h3>
  <input id="hidden_minimum_price" value="100" />
  <input id="hidden_maximum_price" value="50000" />
  <p id="price_show">100 - 50000</p>
  <div class="slide-labels">
    <div class="label pos-0 first">
      $0
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-1">
      $10,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-2">
      $20,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-3">
      $30,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-4">
      $40,000
    </div>
    <div class="label pos-5 last">
      $50,000
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="price_range">
    <div class="tic pos-1">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-2">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-3">
    </div>
    <div class="tic pos-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```